# maven3 - getting error on mvn dependency:tree command

Tags: maven-3

I've a project that uses maven 3. I get the following error when I run mvn dependency:tree command. Could someone advise why would I get this error?

"mvn -version" 
Apache Maven 3.0 (r1004208; 2010-10-04 07:50:56-0400) 
Java version: 1.6.0_16

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.7:tree (default-cli) on project : Cannot build project dependency graph: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getProjectBuildingRequest() -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.7:tree (default-cli) on project wesp-dgw: Cannot build project dependency graph
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot build project dependency graph
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.TreeMojo.execute(TreeMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyGraphBuilderException: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getProjectBuildingRequest()
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(DefaultDependencyGraphBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.TreeMojo.execute(TreeMojo.java:216)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getProjectBuildingRequest()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.invoke(Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder.java:68)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Just try to delete the whole local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository` and make a new build and afterwards retry using the `mvn dependency:tree` again. It looks like there seemed to be some problems while downloading some artifacts which might be caused by some problems with network, proxies etc.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried deleting .m2 repo and rebuilt the project and tried mvn dependency:tree. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error goes away with maven 3.0.5. I'm not sure whether that was a bug in maven 3.0 or configuration issue.

Comment: I experienced exactly this issue with elasticsearch 1.2.1 and Maven 3.0. Upgrading to 3.0.5 also fixed it.

Comment: This surfaced for me with maven 3.3.9 and dependency-plugin 2.7.  Updating dependency-plugin to 2.10 fixed it for me.  Commonality there with the OP being dependency-plugin 2.7.

Comment: same here. I was on  dependency-plugin 2.6 and changing it into  dependency-plugin 2.10 solved the issue